# Is it possible to convert List to HList without infer types?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm new to shapeless and I doing this

```
val list1 = List(1, 2, 3)
val list2 = List("a", "b", "c")

val lists = List(list1, list2)
val hlist = lists.toHList[List[Int] :: List[String] :: HNil]
```

This is fine but I want to create my HList when I won't know the size and types of my List *lists*. Is it possible? If not, is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

To give you some context this is my use case

```
case class Data[T: ClassTag](list: List[T])

trait Transformation {
  type T
  type U
  def transform(data: Data[T]) : Data[U]
}

class FromInt2String extends Transformation {
  override type T = Int
  override type U = String

  override def transform(data: Data[T]) = new Data(List("1s", "2s", "3s"))
}

class FromString2Int extends Transformation {
  override type T = String
  override type U = Int

  override def transform(data: Data[T]) = new Data(List(4, 5, 6))
}

object andThen extends Poly2 {
  implicit def functions[A, B, C] = at[A => B, B => C](_ andThen _)
}
```

These are my objects and this is my code

```
val data = new Data(List(1, 2, 3))
val int2String = new FromInt2String()
val string2Int = new FromString2Int()

val transformationsHList = int2String.transform _ :: string2Int.transform _ :: HNil
val functions = transformationsHList.reduceLeft(andThen)
val data2 = functions(data)
```

I tried to do something like this

```
val transformationsList = List[Transformation](int2String, string2Int)
val transformations = allTransformations.toHList
```

Comment: `HList` is about statically tracking element types, so no, this isn't really possible as stated, but given your use case there may be a way to represent the information you need.

Comment: Thanks Travis for your answer